# prepare_attention API of tensorflow 1.0.0 equivalent in tensorflow 1.2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the equivalent API in tensorflow 1.2.0 for `prepare_attention(tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention)` of tensorflow 1.0.0?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11199), they tell that prepare_attention has been replaced by object-oriented API.

The main class of this API is `tf.contrib.seq2seq.DynamicAttentionWrapper`. See its doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/DynamicAttentionWrapper).